# why there is jitter in autolayout constraint movement

Tags: ios, autolayout, nslayoutconstraint

I am updating height constraints in code in viewdidload and this causes a movement in screen.

Basically I am changing the height based on some values in viewdidload... I can know the values in viewdidload only

How can I get rid of this movement as it appears like jitter and its not visually pleasing

Comment: update  it in  `viewDidAppear`

Comment: Please show code.

Comment: I am just updating the height constrain in my code in viewdidload thats all